# Cleanness vs Cleanliness

Tags: meaning

I only heard "cleanness" for the first time yesterday - I did not know this word existed.

So what's the difference between cleanness and cleanliness?

I've read this http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=973672 but am not clear when I would use "cleanness"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might help to consider that, on the one hand, *cleanliness* is derived from the dated adjective *cleanly*, which means

> (of a person or animal) habitually clean and careful to avoid dirt.
>
> <sup>— [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1233601#m_en_us1233601)</sup>

On the other hand, *cleanness* is derived from the adjective *clean*, which has the following basic meanings:

> 1. free from dirt, marks, or stains:
> 2. morally uncontaminated; pure; innocent:
> 3. free from irregularities; having a smooth edge or surface:
>
> <sup>— [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1233595#m_en_us1233595) *(Visit for elaboration on various meanings and usage)*</sup>

The word *cleanness* can thus be used in any of the senses of the word, *clean*, in reference to people, places, things (inanimate and abstract e.g. buildings, sounds, etc.), actions, and so forth. Also, note that *cleanliness* can only be used for people or animals.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from [The Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=88):

**Cleanliness** is a much more common word than **cleanness**.
They look similar and are certainly related.

But **cleanness** is usually used to refer to the senses of clean that have to do with shape, appearance, or impression (such as "pleasingly simple" and "having edges that are straight and smooth"):

> The **cleanness**, tidiness, and manageability of city life kept surprising her.

> …the bareness, **cleanness**, and sobriety of Doric architecture.

> The performance showed all the technical exactitude and **cleanness** of tone that earlier music demands.

**Cleanliness** refers to being clean or not messy or dirty:

> The restaurant's kitchen is regularly inspected for **cleanliness**.

> His habits of personal hygiene and **cleanliness** were learned in the army.

> She was much concerned with the **cleanliness** of public bathrooms.

Comment: yeah i read that on http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=88 as well, better you credit stuff you lift next time ? So is `cleanness` mainly used in an architectural/structural context?

Comment: I was trying to help you out from where I got the help. Don't take it otherwise.

Comment: @Akshay Thakur: You can always quote your sources, give links, _and_ paraphrase the answer here.

Comment: Thanks , but as a newbie I didn't explored all these stuffs yet.

Comment: @Akshay: Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Akshay Thakur: +1 It is a good answer, and yes, welcome to the site:-)